# facebook search api on graph.facebook.com

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an application to find people on facebook using using the graph search api.
I am using this url in the graph api with access token that has all the permissions

> http://graph.facebook.com/search?q={profileName}&type=user

it seems like its working good but today I tried to search a user I own but couldn't find it there although the user is completely public...

Why?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is part from facebook privacy policy 
check it: https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy

Comment: I defined every field I could find in the privacy settings to public. And when I tried searching for him on the main facebook website I could find him easily, only on the api I couldn't find him.